# How to store the Centroid values of blobs in one Array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

My picture has a certain number of various shapes of blobs. I want to store those centroid values in one array for the future use. So I tried the following code, but it did not work. So can anyone help me?

Sample:

```
for i = 1:length(STATS)
       centroid = STATS(i).Centroid;
       array = zeros(length(STATS));
       array(i) = centroid;
end
```

I want to store the centroid data in one array like below

```
array=

145 145
14  235 
145 544
14  69
74  55
```

Comment: What is `STATS(i).Centroid`? A scalar or a matrix? Is `STATS(1).Centroid = [145 145]`? If not, what is it?

Comment: STATS(1).Centroid=[145 145];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming

```
STATS(1).Centroid = [145 145];
STATS(2).Centroid = [14 235];   % Etc...
```

Try:

```
array = reshape([STATS.Centroid],2,size(STATS,2))' 
array =

   145   145
    14   235
   145   544
    14    69
    74    55
```

**How this works:**

`[STATS.Centroid]` is a short version of `[STATS(1).Centroid, STATS(2).Centroid, .. STATS(n).Centroid]`. This will give you the values as a vector. [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) is then used to make it into your desired size.

Comment: Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in connect (line 61)
array=reshape([STATS.Centroid],2,size(STATS,2));

Comment: @saravana: Try substituting one of the input arguments with `[]`. That is, either use `array=reshape([STATS.Centroid],2,[]);` or `array=reshape([STATS.Centroid],[],size(STATS,2));`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
for i = 1:length(STATS)
   array{i} = STATS(i).Centroid;
end
```

You can print the entire array using the following:

```
array{:}
```

You can read more about cell arrays [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html). Also, in your older code, you were trying to assign an array (`Centroid`) to an element of an array(`array(i)`).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
array=cell2mat({STATS.Centroid});
```